# How to create test stub for a new method using IDEA?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

Suppose you have a new Main class, with 2 methods a and b

Pressing `Control-Shift-T` allows us to create new test class and create stubs for both methods

[image]

Ok, now if i add 1 more method `c`, i'd like to add a test for it in already existing MainTest class

How can this be done please using IDEA? `Control-Shift-T` does not work as it attempts to create an already existing test class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is [not implemented yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90247), please vote for the linked request.

Comment: Click on the arrow below the star icon, you must be logged in.

Answer (score 8):

in Idea 14.x you can press `Alt+Enter` on method names,
if there are some missing tests, you can select option named "**Generate missed test methods**"

[image: Generate missed test methods]

Answer (score 2):

This feature has now been added. CTRL+SHIFT+T | Meta+Shift+T

Comment: I already changed the key mapping of CTRL + SHIFT + T a long time ago. What is the name of the function, so that I can search for it and map it to another key?

Comment: It's under "Keymap: Main Menu->File->Navigate->Test". It's default behavior is to navigate to the test, but if one doesn't exist then it provides an option to create a stub.